# How can i access my local ip address from public network

Tags: android, networking, portforwarding

I'm developing a new android application in which i'm using ip webcam.when user clicks on a button ip web cam will open and it will trigger another phones application where i can watch the video of ip web cam. My problem is i'm getting the video only when i'm in the same network.If i changed to some other network it is not showing.I've searched for the solutions in the internet and i found about port forwarding.I tried that one by like this. If my local ip web cam address is nothing but devices ip address 192.168.1.15, and i'm using the port is 8080,so when i tried to connect with url "192.168.1.15:8080", from same network it is showing, from other network it is not showing.I'm using wireless network and Router is linksys, i opened my router's webpage and in "Application & Gaming ", i set "single port forwarding" by giving the application name, and ip address of the device(192.168.1.15), and port number 8080, and i enabled it.After saving, it is showing settings are successful. but i'm not getting the video.And i tried to check whether port is opened or not by using some port checking websites like "http://www.yougetsignal.com/", but it is always showing that port is closed. I checked some other networking sites saying that try with static ip address of router. I found my router's static (public) ip address by "whatismyip.com", and i tried with that one like "44.126.233.56:8080",still it is not showing the video. I tried with changing of ports like "6564" and "11100", still i'm not getting.So anybody please Help me to get this.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I can help you here or at least point to some idea. 
Your router defines the boundaries of the internet at your house by using an assigned IP (from your ISP) and using an internal IP address for the local network. The internal network IP address is intended to be in a range that the router would not "leak" to the outside - only indirectly by using something that is called NAT - network address translation. The problem that I am having with your question is that if your configuration is set for modem + Linksys and both are capable of processing NAT it will not work (NAT then NAT), your modem should be set for bridge mode and then use the NAT on the Linksys and configure the port triggering or forward as your device would function as game console. Hope this helps.
Thank you

Comment: Actually i'm not using modem, my home network router is linksys, and my other network is a public network.So,is it possible to access my local device from that public network without changing the bridge connections settings of the public network, because public network may be any network, so it will change according to the place where i goes.